# How to create an RTSP server using live 555 on a mac

Tags: c++, macos, stream, rtsp, live555

I am trying to find a method in the live555 class that takes in a 
video file and turns it into a rtsp stream. Could someone please
tell me about this method?

```
int main()
{

scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();


}
```